# placing elements in page background

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a page where its background are rows and columns of animated circles. The page will also have a title in the middle. When I use div to load a column of circles first, the title gets pushed down to the bottom. I know z-index will help bring the circles to the back and keep the title in front. But still, I'm not able to solve the issue. I'm confused about the usage of div and span to do this. I'm also new to CSS. I'd appreciate some guidance.

Here is some of my code:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="circle"></div>
 <div class="circle"></div>
 <div class="circle"></div>
 <div class="circle"></div>
 <center>
 <h1 style=color:black class="hvr-float">Hello</h1>
 <button class="btn btn-default hvr-wobble-horizontal" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Facebook">
 <i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"> </i>
 </button>

<button class="btn btn-default hvr-wobble-horizontal" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Github">
 <i class="fa fa-github fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"> </i>
 </button>

 <button class="btn btn-default hvr-wobble-horizontal" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="LinkedIn">
 <i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"> </i>
 </button>

 <button class="btn btn-default hvr-wobble-horizontal" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Skype">
 <i class="fa fa-skype fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"> </i>
 </button>
 <button class="btn btn-default hvr-wobble-horizontal" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Codepen">
 <i class="fa fa-codepen fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"> </i>
 </button>
 <button class="btn btn-default  hvr-wobble-horizontal " data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Resume">
 <i class="fa fa-file fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"> </i>
 </button>
 <button class="btn btn-default hvr-wobble-horizontal" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Email">
 <i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"> </i>
 </button>
 </center>

    </div>
```

Some CSS for the circle and headings:

```
.circle {
    position:relative;
    left:20px;
    bottom:20px;
    top:20px;
    z-index:-100;

    border-radius: 35px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 35px;
    border-bottom-color:  #FFE097 ;
    border-left-color: #9BE3F4;
    border-right-color:  #9BF4D4 ;
    border-top-color: #FF97E3;
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    transform:rotate(45deg);




    }
h1{
z-index:100;
font: 400 130px/0.8 'Great Vibes', Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: #fff;
text-shadow: 4px 4px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 
position:absolute;
left: 420px;
margin-top: 17%;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Z-index only works on positioned elements. In other words, the position property must have a value other than static or z-index will be ignored.

Comment: I added position:relative; as well as assigned some values to left, bottom etc. but the issue still persists. Its perhaps because I'm making a new <div> for each circle and div creates line breaks regardless?

Comment: No, a div won't create a line break. You need to set position an z-index on every element you want overlap. So if Div1 overlaps Div2, both Div1 and Div2 must have the properties.  Without seeing your CSS code I can't tell why the issue is happening. What's that anyway? Bootstrap?

Comment: Yes, it is bootstrap & posted some of the CSS.

Comment: So h1 is the title getting pushed down, but you haven't set z-index in h1, have you?

Comment: I didn't but I did just now with z-index:100. It is still the same.

Comment: ZzZz. Push it up by lowering margin-top.